# LibGDX RuntimeException: Error parsing emitter: Untitled

Tags: java, libgdx, particles

I am a LibGDX beginner. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void create() {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    bf = new BitmapFont();
    particle = new ParticleEffect();
    particle.load(Gdx.files.internal("particle.p"), Gdx.files.internal("particle.png"));
}
```

And I am getting below error:

> `java.lang.RuntimeException: Error parsing emitter: Untitled
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.load(ParticleEmitter.java:970)
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.<init>(ParticleEmitter.java:94)
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect.newEmitter(ParticleEffect.java:206)
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect.loadEmitters(ParticleEffect.java:157)
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect.load(ParticleEffect.java:137)
>                                                                       at com.mygdx.game.MyGame.create(MyGame.java:35)
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:275)
>                                                                       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1512)
>                                                                       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
>                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "false"
>                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
>                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
>                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
>                                                                       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.readInt(ParticleEmitter.java:993)
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter$GradientColorValue.load(ParticleEmitter.java:1332)
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.load(ParticleEmitter.java:951)
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEmitter.<init>(ParticleEmitter.java:94) 
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect.newEmitter(ParticleEffect.java:206) 
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect.loadEmitters(ParticleEffect.java:157) 
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.ParticleEffect.load(ParticleEffect.java:137) 
>                                                                       at com.mygdx.game.MyGame.create(MyGame.java:35) 
>                                                                       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:275) 
>                                                                       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1512) 
>                                                                       at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)`

the file "Particle.p" content : Untitled - Delay - active: false - Duration - lowMin: 3000.0 lowMax: 3000.0 - Count - min: 0 max: 200 - Emission - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 250.0 highMax: 250.0 relative: false scalingCount: 1 scaling0: 1.0 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - Life - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 500.0 highMax: 1000.0 relative: false scalingCount: 3 scaling0: 1.0 scaling1: 1.0 scaling2: 0.3 timelineCount: 3 timeline0: 0.0 timeline1: 0.66 timeline2: 1.0 - Life Offset - active: false - X Offset - active: false - Y Offset - active: false - Spawn Shape - shape: point - Spawn Width - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 0.0 highMax: 0.0 relative: false scalingCount: 1 scaling0: 1.0 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - Spawn Height - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 0.0 highMax: 0.0 relative: false scalingCount: 1 scaling0: 1.0 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - X Scale - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 32.0 highMax: 32.0 relative: false scalingCount: 1 scaling0: 1.0 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - Y Scale - active: false - Velocity - active: true lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 30.0 highMax: 300.0 relative: false scalingCount: 1 scaling0: 1.0 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - Angle - active: true lowMin: 90.0 lowMax: 90.0 highMin: 45.0 highMax: 135.0 relative: false scalingCount: 3 scaling0: 1.0 scaling1: 0.0 scaling2: 0.0 timelineCount: 3 timeline0: 0.0 timeline1: 0.5 timeline2: 1.0 - Rotation - active: false - Wind - active: false - Gravity - active: false - Tint - colorsCount: 3 colors0: 1.0 colors1: 0.12156863 colors2: 0.047058824 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - Transparency - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 1.0 highMax: 1.0 relative: false scalingCount: 4 scaling0: 0.0 scaling1: 1.0 scaling2: 0.75 scaling3: 0.0 timelineCount: 4 timeline0: 0.0 timeline1: 0.2 timeline2: 0.8 timeline3: 1.0 - Options - attached: false continuous: false aligned: false additive: true behind: false premultipliedAlpha: false - Image Path - particle.png

Untitled - Delay - active: false - Duration - lowMin: 3000.0 lowMax: 3000.0 - Count - min: 0 max: 200 - Emission - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 250.0 highMax: 250.0 relative: false scalingCount: 1 scaling0: 1.0 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - Life - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 500.0 highMax: 1000.0 relative: false scalingCount: 3 scaling0: 1.0 scaling1: 1.0 scaling2: 0.3 timelineCount: 3 timeline0: 0.0 timeline1: 0.66 timeline2: 1.0 - Life Offset - active: false - X Offset - active: false - Y Offset - active: false - Spawn Shape - shape: point - Spawn Width - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 0.0 highMax: 0.0 relative: false scalingCount: 1 scaling0: 1.0 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - Spawn Height - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 0.0 highMax: 0.0 relative: false scalingCount: 1 scaling0: 1.0 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - X Scale - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 32.0 highMax: 32.0 relative: false scalingCount: 1 scaling0: 1.0 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - Y Scale - active: false - Velocity - active: true lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 30.0 highMax: 300.0 relative: false scalingCount: 1 scaling0: 1.0 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - Angle - active: true lowMin: 90.0 lowMax: 90.0 highMin: 45.0 highMax: 135.0 relative: false scalingCount: 3 scaling0: 1.0 scaling1: 0.0 scaling2: 0.0 timelineCount: 3 timeline0: 0.0 timeline1: 0.5 timeline2: 1.0 - Rotation - active: false - Wind - active: false - Gravity - active: false - Tint - colorsCount: 3 colors0: 1.0 colors1: 0.12156863 colors2: 0.047058824 timelineCount: 1 timeline0: 0.0 - Transparency - lowMin: 0.0 lowMax: 0.0 highMin: 1.0 highMax: 1.0 relative: false scalingCount: 4 scaling0: 0.0 scaling1: 1.0 scaling2: 0.75 scaling3: 0.0 timelineCount: 4 timeline0: 0.0 timeline1: 0.2 timeline2: 0.8 timeline3: 1.0 - Options - attached: false continuous: false aligned: false additive: true behind: false premultipliedAlpha: false - Image Path - particle.png `

this file "particle.p" is to use particle generator generated, I don't know whats wrong, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the cause of the problem, I use the particle generator and LibGDX don't fit.In particle generator has a Scale and a Scale X label and a Scale Y label, but LibGDX text parser only parse a Scale label, cause parsing errors, causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've already solved your problem but just letting you know that updating your LibGDX to 1.9.7-SNAPSHOT will help solve the issue.

If you're on Android Studio (like I am, not sure about other IDEs). You can update through build.gradle.

Just change the line

```
gdxVersion='YOUR_CURRENT_VERSION'
```

to

```
gdxVersion = '1.9.7-SNAPSHOT'
```